# Updating a list entry as a value to a nested dictionary

Tags: list, dictionary, nested, key

I have the following nested dictionary: facebook. You'll note that one of the key value pairs is friends: ["friend1","friend2" etc). In trying to append the various friends to the list, it does so but not in the correct format.

**Question 1**: Could someone please provide an answer/solution to solve this problem. The desired output on appending the information given should be in the same format as for John and Mary (keys) in the dictionary.

**Note:** the keys are: **John, Mary**  (and in register_user, I attempt to add the key: **Mr x**) The values are as shown, where the **friends for each individual (key) are stored in a list**. What I am not sure of is, when you "append" keys and values to a dictionary, you can add the values, but how do you add the keys, or reference the keys when adding the values?

**Code so far:**

```
facebook={'John': {'Friends': ['Bobby', 'Charlie', 'Dalia', 'Ellie'],
            'Gender': 'Male',
            'Hobby': 'Chess'},


            'Mary': {'Friends': ['Bobby', 'Xavier', 'Dalia', 'Zanpoodle'],
            'Gender': 'Female',
            'Hobbies': 'Chequers'}}

def main():
  register_user()

#create a dictionary that stores the profiles of users 


def register_user():
  name=input("Enter Name:")
  friend1=input("Friend 1:")
  friend2=input("Friend 2:")
  friend3=input("Friend 3:")
  friend4=input("Friend 4:")
  #gender=input("Enter Gender:")
  #hobby=input("Enter your main hobby:")

  #this adds an entry to the dictionary
  facebook.update({name:[friend1,friend2,friend3,friend4]})
  for i in facebook.items():
    print(i)

  print()

  print(facebook.items())


main()
```

**Erroneous output:**
*As mentioned, I would like Friend1, Friend 2 etc, to be added to a list value for key: friends, in Mr X's new entry.

```
Enter Name: Mr X
Friend 1: Friend1
Friend 2: Friend2
Friend 3: Friend3
Friend 4: Friend4
('John', {'Friends': ['Bobby', 'Charlie', 'Dalia', 'Ellie'], 'Gender': 'Male', 'Hobby': 'Chess'})
('Mary', {'Friends': ['Bobby', 'Xavier', 'Dalia', 'Zanpoodle'], 'Gender': 'Female', 'Hobbies': 'Chequers'})
('Mr X', ['Friend1', 'Friend2', 'Friend3', 'Friend4'])

dict_items([('John', {'Friends': ['Bobby', 'Charlie', 'Dalia', 'Ellie'], 'Gender': 'Male', 'Hobby': 'Chess'}), ('Mary', {'Friends': ['Bobby', 'Xavier', 'Dalia', 'Zanpoodle'], 'Gender': 'Female', 'Hobbies': 'Chequers'}), **('Mr X', ['Friend1', 'Friend2', 'Friend3', 'Friend4'])])**
```

**Update:**
**I also tried this:**
    facebook.update({name:{Friends:[friend1,friend2,friend3,friend4]}})

**but it came up with the following error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 35, in <module>
  File "python", line 11, in main
  File "python", line 26, in register_user
NameError: name 'Friends' is not defined
```

**Another try:**

```
facebook[name]={'Friends':[friend1,friend2,friend3,friend4]}
```

**unfortunately still an error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 35, in <module>
  File "python", line 11, in main
  File "python", line 27, in register_user
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

Finally, I have also tried adding the names to a list and then appending this list like this:

```
   newfriends=[friend1,friend2,friend3,friend4]
   facebook.update({name:{[newfriends]})
```

**Resultant in a syntax error**

along with just trying to use **append:**

```
friendslist=[friend1,friend2,friend3,friend4]
  facebook['name'].append(friendlist)
```

**ERROR:**

```
KeyError: 'name'
```

**This attempt gets close, but not quite:**

```
facebook.update({"Name":name,"Friends":[friend1,friend2,friend3,friend4]})
```

producing the following output:

```
Enter Name: t
Friend 1: 1
Friend 2: 2
Friend 3: 3
Friend 4: 4
{'John': {'Friends': ['Bobby', 'Charlie', 'Dalia', 'Ellie'], 'Gender': 'Male', 'Hobby': 'Chess'}, 'Mary': {'Friends': ['Bobby', 'Xavier', 'Dalia', 'Zanpoodle'], 'Gender': 'Female', 'Hobbies': 'Chequers'}, 'Name': 't', 'Friends': ['1', '2', '3', '4']}
```

Clarification: I realise there may be several different ways of approaching this. I would like a simple fix to the problem **WITHOUT introducing anything new** (like lambda or having to import anything)

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve your problem is to convert the `facebook` dictionary to a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd_facebook = defaultdict(lambda: {"Friends": []}, facebook)
```

To update the friends list you could simply do the following:

```
dd_facebook[name]['Friends'].extend([friend1,friend2,friend3,friend4])
```

Comment: This doesn't work. On using the input: Mr X, friend1,friend2,friend3,friend4, it results in: KeyError: 'Mr X'. I think my question could do with an upvote...this will be very helpful to people and I did check for duplicates. :)

Comment: Thanks for this, but I do just want an answer that solves the problem as-is, without introducing lambda and the need to import. For teaching purposes, this should be relatively simple to do - all I need to do is add an entry with mulitple keys to the dictionary! I'm hoping someone can help

Comment: @MissComputing You were looking for the most pythonic way. This answer is pretty pythonic. If you want something else, your question should be more precise.

Comment: This is certainly another method, although unverified as yet, but I want a simple fix to the above code - it is a syntax rather than anything else error, I assume? Thanks for the unnecessary downvote (I didn't downvote you when your answer was initially WRONG), and you're welcome for an upvote now: Finally, I have clarified my question so as not to include introducing anything other than what is already in the code